# Trying to store POINT geometry using Laravel Backpack

Tags: crud, laravel-backpack, laravel-9

I'm using Backpack to display CRUD for various MYSQL database tables.
One of the tables contains a POINT type.

I am using the
Grimzy package to to handle the POINT elsewhere like so:

```
   // Convert point from JSON coordinates to a MYSQL Point
$pnt = new Point($input['MonitoringPointGISLocation']['coordinates'][1],
                 $input['MonitoringPointGISLocation']['coordinates'][0]);

$input['MonitoringPointGISLocation'] = $pnt;
```

The CRUD controller contains

```
CRUD::column('MonitoringPointGISLocation')->label('GIS Location');
```

when I run an update I get the following error

[image: Error for Backpack CRUD]

What is the correct formulation to save a POINT to the database with Backpack?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using the SpatialTrait on your eloquent model?
Also make sure you include your mysql column name in the $spatialFields array.

https://github.com/grimzy/laravel-mysql-spatial#create-a-model